# Using 'at' command for timed video recording the next day and do it only once

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, cron

I'm trying to 
`1) start and stream video to vlc` and 
`2) record the same video stream to a file that starts at 05:45 am the next day` everything works but the start time, instead of starting at 05:45 am the next day it starts immediately.  What did I miss?

```
bash -c "streamlink --stdout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOacA3RYrXk 720p | tee /tmp/water_vid/water_video-$(date +"%H:%M_%m-%d-%Y").mkv | vlc -" | at 05:45 am
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is equivalent of:

```
notify-send "Hello" | at now +1 minute
```

Where the `notify-send` command will be executed immediately and nothing will be piped to the standard input of `at`. By using `atq` to get the latest job number and `at -c <job-number>` we can see what actually will be executed. So the analyse of the above job will show nothing:

```
$ at -c "$(atq | sort | awk 'END{print $1}')" | grep 'Hello'
```

**The proper syntax is to use `echo` to output your command as a string that will be piped to the standard input of the command `at`**:

```
echo 'notify-send "Hello"' | at now +1 minute
```

In this case the output of the analyse of the latest job will be different:

```
$ at -c "$(atq | sort | awk 'END{print $1}')" | grep 'Hello'
notify-send "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at man at I am assuming you should specify 5:45am, without space. It also allows you to specify tomorrow, so I would try "at 5:45am tomorrow"

Comment: Hello, the white space doesn't matter here :)